# Как сделать тень со всех сторон изображения?

Tags: html, css

Хочу6 чтобы у картинки c четырёх сторон была тень. Но тень только с одной стороны.

```css
    .home__inner{
        height: 630px;
    }
    
    .home__title h1{
        font-weight:800;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 60px;
        width: 50%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 108px;
    
    }
    
    .home__img{
        margin:0 56%;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 15px 10px #000;
    z-index: 1;
    }
```

```html
      <div class="home__inner">
            <div class="home__title">
                <h1>Our Strong Organaisation</h1>
            </div>
        <div class="home__img">
            <img src="Company.jpg" alt="" width="551px" height="356px">
        </div>
    
        </div>
```

Comment: Ваш зашкаливающий `margin: 0 56%` схлопывает размер блока в ноль

Comment: Что мне делать???
Убрать Margin????????????????????????????????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Регулируй margin и width картинки

```css
    .home__inner{
        height: 630px;
    }
    
    .home__title h1{
        font-weight:800;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 60px;
        width: 50%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 108px;
    
    }
    
    .home__img{
      margin-left: 40%;
      width: 500px;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 15px 10px #000;
    z-index: 1;
    }
```

```html
      <div class="home__inner">
            <div class="home__title">
                <h1>Our Strong Organaisation</h1>
            </div>
        <div class="home__img">
            <img src="Company.jpg" alt="" width="551px" height="356px">
        </div>
    
        </div>
```